# How to use data with different length for cnn with conv1 as first layer?

Tags: keras, input, conv-neural-network

I have a list of arrays of different shapes i.e.

```
list = [array([1,2,3]), dtype=int16), 
            array([1,2,3,4,5]), dtype=int16), 
            array([1,2]), dtype=int16),
            array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]), dtype=int16)]
```

I want to use these data as input in a cnn in which the first layer is conv1. How should i transform the data in order to work? Should i fill with `zeros` the arrays? The data is signal coming from a heart device.d

Answer (score 0):

Every sample data has to have same shape to feed any Keras model as you know, therefore you have to make all sample's shape same. In order to do so, you can leverage sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer to full with dummy numbers to make the shapes same.
The SimpleImputer has some options to fill out, please refer below site.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer.html

If the smallest sample shape (e.g. [1, 2]) is still relatively big, you can prune other sample's data in order to fit to the smallest shape. If the smallest one is still small, you should consider whether you should omit it or not.

Given data is heart beat wave data, I'll try with zero as you mentioned at first.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I processed my data using pad function and my final data have the same shape ```(8528, 18286)```. Based on whice criterion should i decide whether it is big or small?

Comment: I will recommend you to feed every dataset you can come up with, it is trial and error thing. So, we do not have clear answer especially with regard to the size of dataset, since it depends on your problem and model you tune. Like computer vision problem with CNN, nobody can say how many pictures are significant.